# Save Cart items for customer in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to know if such kind of modules are available in prestashop where user can add some products in his/her cart and it will be store until he delete from cart.

Like if users having products in his cart and logout without purchasing, next time he log in to the system and those products should be still there.

Comment: Uhh that's how prestashop already does it.

Comment: i have just installed a fresh copy of prestashop. its not working. what happen is when i logout and login again it shows my cart is empty  but when i add a new product to my cart then its show the previous products.

Comment: Ok, go to backoffice `Preferences->Customers` and set `Re-display cart at login` to Yes and see if that works.